# Convert matrix of json arrays to vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
1   ["oak brook location"]
2   ["place", "Bar service", "bunch of kids", "Admin hours"]
3   ["food", "ice cold"]
```

And I want to extract a vector from it like:

```
[1]   "oak brook location"  "place"  "Bar service"  "bunch of kids"  "Admin hours"  "food"  "ice cold"
```

Since the original data is collection of json arrays, I am trying to use the jsonlite package to do this.  But I am not exactly how to go about this.  Can someone help with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the correct approach, but I used a loop and ran the fromJSON function and appended to a new vector to get this accomplished.

```
for(i in frameWithJsonArray[[2]]){newVector <- append(newVector, fromJSON(i), after = length(newVector))}
```